# Mac OS X/Wine - Associating file extension (.php) with a Windows program on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, wine, pspad

I am running [PSPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPad) (a Windows programming editor) on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) using Wine 1.1.35.

I want to associate various file extensions (.php, .js, .html) with `PSPad.exe`.

Finder does not allow this association. I can only associate file types with `$.app` items in Applications.

How do I get Mac OS X to pass a file to Wine/PSPad when I double click it in Finder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an AppleScript (or other Mac executable) that wraps PSPad.exe and Wine, which you can then associate in the Finder with those file types. See http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/FAQs#head-8ce99bcac8d68bfcc6f7c58895110da202927611 for some instructions on doing that.

Comment: Thanks Jon -- tried this and while it does create an app which can be associated with file types, it fails to open a file (filename.php) in the editor when double clicking on filename.php.  I've given up trying to get this to work and switched to jEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it would work, but you could create a symbolic link called `whatever.app` and have that link to the `PSPad.exe` file.